# Why express call my get route and not my put route?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have the following route in my express application:

```
router.get('/edit/:id', (req, res)=> {
    let searchQuery = {_id : req.params.id};
    console.log(searchQuery)
    Address.findOne(searchQuery)
        .then(address => {
            res.render('myForm', {address:address});
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });

});
```

and my form is:

```
 <form action="/edit/<%= address.id %>?_method=put" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
      <br>
      <input type="text" value="<%= address.name %>" name="name" class="form-control">
      <br>
      <input type="text" value="<%= address.email %>" name="email" class="form-control">
      <br>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block mt-3">Update User</button>
  </form>
```

It works correctly, I can see the data getting form the mongodb into myForm. Now after I update some data in this form and click the udpdate button i get : `Cannot POST /edit/62185a7efd51425bbf43e21a`

Noting that I have the following route:

```
router.put('/edit/:id', (req, res)=> {
    let searchQuery = {_id : req.params.id};
    console.log(`searchQuery = ${searchQuery}`)
    Address.updateOne(searchQuery, {$set: {
        name: _.extend(name, req.body),
        email: req.body.email,

    }})
    .then(address => {
        res.redirect('/');
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.redirect('/');
    });
});
```

It looks like express call the get and not the put in my case. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser itself will only do GET and PUT from a `<form>`.  So, your browser is sending a POST and your server doesn't have a handler for that POST.

The `?_method=put` that you added to your URL looks like you're hoping to use some sort of method conversion or override tool on the server so that it will recognize that form POST as if it were a PUT.  You don't show any server-side code to recognize that override query parameter so apparently your server is just receiving the POST and doesn't have a handler and thus you get the error `CANNOT POST /edit/62185a7efd51425bbf43e21a`.

There are several different middleware solutions that can perform this override.  Here's one from Express: http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/method-override.html and you can see how to deploy/configure it in that document.

Basically, you would install the module with:

```
npm install method-override
```

and then add this to your server:

```
const methodOverride = require('method-override')

// override with POST having ?_method=PUT
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
```

This will look at incoming POST requests with the `?_method=PUT` query string and will modify the method per the parameter in the query string so that `app.put()` will then match it.

This is to be used when the client can only do GET or POST and can't do other useful methods such as PUT or DELETE.

---

As a demonstration, this simple app works and outputs `got it!` back to the browser and `/edit/123456789?_method=put` in the server console when I press the Update User button in the HTML form.

```
const app = require('express')();
const path = require('path');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');


app.use(methodOverride('_method'));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "temp.html"));
});

app.put('/edit/:id', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.url);

    res.send("got it!");
});

app.listen(80);
```

And, `temp.html` is this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/edit/123456789?_method=put" method="POST">
         <br>
         <input type="text" value="hello" name="name" class="form-control">
         <br>
         <input type="text" value="hello@gmail.com" name="email" class="form-control">
         <br>

         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block mt-3">Update User</button>
     </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: after addinng what you suggest i get the following error Cannot PUT /edit/62185a7efd51425bbf43e21a

Comment: @bib - I'd have to see exactly what code you're now using (client and server) in order to help further.   `router.put('/edit/:id', ...)` should match `/edit/62185a7efd51425bbf43e21a?_method=put` unless you have some other error in how the router is set up.

Comment: please the original post. I already added the router.put('/edit/:id, ...)

Comment: @bib - When implemented properly, it works.  See the sample server app I added to my answer.

Comment: can you please explain to me why we add   <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">

Comment: @bib - That is not necessary.  That is one of several methods that the override library can use to specify the PUT verb.  The recommendation here is to use the `?_method=put"` technique.

Answer (score -1):

You can create chainable route handlers for a route path by using app.route(). Because the path is specified at a single location, creating modular routes is helpful, as is reducing redundancy and typos.
**Note**: you must change the method in side form tag to PUT

```
<form action="/edit/<%= address.id %>" method="put">
//Backend.js
router.route('/edit/:id')
 .get((req, res) => {
    res.send('Get a random book')
 })
.put((req, res) => {
  res.send('Update the book')
})
```

Comment: Uhhh, Chrome (and probably other browsers too) don't support anything other than GET or POST for form submissions.  You can use other http verbs like PUT via `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch()`, but not via a form submission don't via `<form action="xxx" method="yyy">`.  Try it yourself in Chrome.  If you find a way that your `<form>` tag you show works, then comment back.  When I tried it, it doesn't work.  It just results in a GET.