# How to use router.put() method on a express.js app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, http

I'm trying to use the update functionality on a Express.js app using a simple json file as database, but I keep getting errors when i use a PUT request to send the new data. I've the following code in my files:
On my routes folder i have a **user.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();
const fs = require("fs");
const { nanoid } = require('nanoid');
var userData = require('../database/users.json');
var users = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./database/users.json', 'UTF-8'));

/* Rendering the form with data from a specific id ???this part works */
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
var id = req.params.id; //  contains data from :id
var userDetails = users.find(user => user.id === id); // find user from users using .find method
    
    //get the user data content array from json file based on id
   
    let picked = (({ name, content, url, id }) => ({ name, content, url, id }))(userDetails);

    console.log(picked);

     // send the data
    res.render('user', {title: 'user', data: picked  });    
});

/* Update - Put method ??? don´t work */
router.put('/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    //get the id from url
    var id = req.params.id; // will contains data from :id 


var userDetails = users.find(user => user.id === id); // find user from users using .find method
    
   
    //get the user data content array from json file based on id
    let picked = (({ name, content, url, id }) => ({ name, content, url, id }))(userDetails);

    
//get the update data
const userData = req.body;

//update the user data array based on id with req.body ???
    var newUserData = picked.push(userData);
            
  console.log(newUserData); //I get a error
   
});

module.exports = router;
```

On my views folder i got a **user.ejs:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <p>Welcome to <%= title %> </p>
    <h2>Testing Form to Handle Data</h2>
       
<form action="user/:id" method="put">
  Name:<input type="text"  value="<%= data.name%>"  name="username">
  content:<input type="text"  value="<%= data.content%>" name="usercontent">
  url:<input type="text" value="<%= data.url%>" name="userurl">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
      
<ul>
  <li>Visit the <a href="/users">users</a> page.</li>
  <li>Visit the <a href="/">home</a> page.</li>
</ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

The **json file:**

```
[
{"name":"test name1","content":"test content 1","url":"test url 1","id":"LbxWoV1J-qbRZd1QLSqg_"}
]
```

I don't understand what is going wrong.

Comment: _"//I get a error"_. Would be useful if you actually shared the error.

Comment: Sorry this is the error I get Not Found
404
NotFoundError: Not Found

Comment: See the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71418691/why-express-call-my-get-route-and-not-my-put-route/71418738#71418738) yours has been marked a dup of for more explanation.  The short answer is that browsers only support GET and POST from forms.  If you specify something other than that, they do a GET.  There are work-arounds by putting the actual desired method in a hidden form element or in a query parameter.